# A cosa si riferisce l'aggettivo "compita" in questa lettera dell'Ottocento?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Lipari li 8 Novembre 1856 
>   Ho caricato col nome di Dio a buon salvamento una volta tanto in questo porto di Sotto il Monastero per conto e rischio del signor Ferlazzo Onofrio sopra e sotto coperta della sua Nominata San 
>   Cristoforo al comando di Bartolomeo Barbuto per condurre e consegnare 
>   in questo suo presente viaggio in Cefalù le appiè nominate, e numerate mercanzie sciutte, intiere, e ben condizionate, segnate come di contro, 
>   
>   e così promette detto Capitano al suo salvo arrivo consegnarle al Signor Michelangelo Di Paola e di nolo gli sarà pagato secondo contratto 
>   
>   e per fede del vero sarà questa con altre simili firmata da detto Capitano e non sapendo egli scrivere, per lui da terza persona ed una **compita** le altre restino di niun valore. 
>   
>   C. 1428. Dico Cantàra mille quattrocento ventotto pietra pomice 
>   S. 175. Dico Salme cento settanta cinque vino malvasìa 
>   
>   N. 7. Dico Numero sette barili di càpperi salati qualità puntina.

Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho visto che "compito" significa "portato o giunto a termine" oppure "completo, pieno", ma non riesco a capire a cosa fa riferimento questo "compita" che appare in questa lettera. Che cosa, una volta "compita", fa che "le altre restino di niun valore"?

Comment: Potrebbe significare che la lettera è stata scritta in più copie simili da terza persona ed una compita. Qui compita potrebbe essere voce del verbo [compitare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/compitare/) cioè "Leggere lentamente, distinguendo e pronunciando separatamente i varî suoni di cui sono formate le parole o dividendo le sillabe" anche per fare in modo che il Capitano potesse ascoltare la lettura del documento per verificare che quanto scritto corrispondesse a quanto stabilito.

Answer (score 2):

Potrebbe significare che la lettera è stata scritta in più copie simili da terza persona ed una compita. Qui compita potrebbe essere voce del verbo [compitare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/compitare/) cioè:

> "Leggere lentamente, distinguendo e pronunciando separatamente i varî
>   suoni di cui sono formate le parole o dividendo le sillabe"

anche per fare in modo che il Capitano potesse ascoltare la lettura del documento per verificare che quanto scritto corrispondesse a quanto stabilito.

Answer (score 2):

Qui a mio modo di vedere *compita* significa *compiuta*.

La mia lettura del brano proposto mi dice che la lettera di contratto esiste in più copie e che quando il Capitano Bartolomeo Barbuto consegnerà le merci al Signor Michelangelo Di Paola e verrà da questi pagato una delle copie sarà considerata *compita*, restando in possesso del Di Paola come ricevuta del pagamento mentre le altre *restino di niun valore*.

La lettera viene considerata *compita* o *compiuta* perché le obbligazioni (consegna, pagamento) individuate dalla lettera sono state soddisfatte o *compiute* e quindi, per esteso, la lettera stessa risulta *compiuta*.

Comment: Ha senso, ma si tratterebbe di "[compiere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/compiere)" con quale significato?

Comment: _Compita_ come _compiuta_ in quanto le diverse obbligazioni (consegna, pagamento) descritte nella lettera sono compiute e quindi per traslato la lettera stessa è compiuta.  Forse è meglio se integro la risposta, vero?

Comment: Quindi, il significato della frase sarebbe che, una volta si è fatto tutto quello che si chiede nella lettera, se appare qualcuno con un'altra copia, questa non dovrebbe avere nessun valore e quindi non si dovrebbe fare di nuovo tutto quello che si spiega nella lettera. Veramente ha senso.

Comment: @Charo La spiegazione che ti ho proposto è sensata, lo riconosco... tra le diverse ipotesi che ho fatto è la più sensata.  Se sia quella corretta onestamente non lo so, io al momento non approverei la mia risposta. Il +1 invece mi sta bene :)